# how to make array 4D with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have so many data when execute distinct query, 
example on this image 
[a busy cat http://www.admedika2u.com/data-1.jpg](http://www.admedika2u.com/data-1.jpg)

I want group final status, that have nodeid, portid and total which mean total status.

make an array like this

```
[
  [a => b] => c
] => d
```

any ideas...?

Comment: What kind of idea do you want? Creating 4d array in php is exactly the same as 3d and 2d and 1d.

Comment: why dont u just use an array of objects?

Comment: `$array['a']['b']['c'] = 'd';` You can go as deep as you want. They are all the same thing.

Comment: i mean that a = total, b = portID, c = nodeID, d = FinalStatus

Comment: So `$array[$total][$portID][$nodeID] = $finalStatus;`

Comment: That is php code. It runs and compiles just fine. You just need to add a loop around it and set the variables.

Comment: I wish somebody will show it into tabels

Comment: Are you expecting someone to just write the code for you? That's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total = $row['total'];
    $port = $row['PortID'];
    $node = $row['NodeID'];
    $final = $row['FinalStatus'];
    if (!isset($result[$total])) {
        $result[$total] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($result[$total][$port])) {
        $result[$total][$port] = array();
    }
    $result[$total][$port][$node] = $final;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the capitalization right in `PortID` and `NodeID`. Try the update.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can put however many dimensions on an array as you want. Here it looks like you need a three-dimensional array, that would store values (the fourth value).

If you have the variables $final_status $node_id, $port_id and $total_status you can set them into a multidimensional array like this:

```
$my_array[$final_status][$node_id][$port_id] = $total_status;
```

If you loop through and do that with everything in your table you could later look up a total_status with actual vales:

```
$total_status = $my_array[55][2000][32]
```

However, I would like to mention that big multidimensional arrays like this are probably not the best way to store data. Perhaps you need to create a few classes of object that can store your data in a more accessible way.

Comment: thats why i asking, because no class exist in the database